# peculiar behavior of rxjs SwitchMap while calling an HTTP Service

Tags: angular, rxjs, switchmap

I have rxjs SwitchMap which calls an HTTP service that returns an HTTP observable. But the switchmap hits only the first time or until the first result retrieved. after that it does not execute no matter how much I push in behavior or replay subject.

```
selectedView$ = new ReplaySubject<View>();

ngOnInit(): void {
    combineLatest(([this.selectedView$, this.customer$]))
    .pipe(
      switchMap(([view, customer]) => {
        //this.loading = true;
        return this.cogniteService.getCogniteWellbores(customer.id, view?.cognite?.projectName, View.getPerimeter(view));
      }),
      tap(wb => {
        this.store.dispatch(this.cogniteActions.loadWellbores(wb));
        this.loading = false;
      }),
      catchError( err => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
        this.showError.showError(err);
        return of(0);
      }),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

while I do next to the selectedView it does not hit the switchmap part. But if put any other code without this HTTP call. then it hits. such as:

```
combineLatest(([this.selectedView$, this.customer$]))
    .pipe(
      switchMap(([view, customer]) => {
        //this.loading = true;
        return new Observable<Wellbore[]>();
      }),
      tap(wb => {
        this.store.dispatch(this.cogniteActions.loadWellbores(wb));
        this.loading = false;
      }),
      catchError( err => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
        this.showError.showError(err);
        return of(0);
      }),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$)
 ).subscribe();
```

Comment: I think switchMap will be executed if it received a new event fire, calling it in the ngOninit it will be called once

Comment: i call it via selectedview.next(something); but it won't execute. should it?

Comment: And how the this.selectedView$ will be fired?

Comment: i will select a dropdown and it will call a function where it will execute selectedView$.next(something);

Comment: Could you create a Stackblitz with mock data?

Comment: Why didn't put this code in the onChange function related to dropdown selection

Comment: What is in your `this.cogniteService.getCogniteWellbores`?

Comment: That is returning an Observable. the method is fetching an http

Comment: Are you sure that `this.cogniteService.getCogniteWellbores(customer.id,....)` returns something? I mean, did you try to place a simple `console.log('I entered SwitchMap)` just after the call to `getCogniteWellbores` to see whether it returns? Apologies for the silly suggestion, but I do not see why your code should not work if your API responds.

Comment: it is not hitting through this.cogniteService.getCogniteWellbores(customer.id,....) this code at all.

Comment: yes that console.log didn't execute